# Alternative to explicit instantiation on networked framewok

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, network-programming

I am writing a distributed programming framework and I have reached a wall on what it comes to templated object declaration and creation on client side. The problem is that I have a object that I need to create in the client side of the network. Somewhere in the client I have:

At Server Side:

```
template <typename T>
class myRemoteObject{
    myRemoteObject<T>(){
        // tells client to create an object of type T
        sendCreateObject( encodeType(T) );     // This is working
    }
};

int main(){
    ...
    myRemoteObject obj;
    ...
}
```

At the client side:

```
case (message.type){
    OBJ_TYPE_INT:
        objPtr = new myObject<int>();
        break;
    OBJ_TYPE_FLOAT:
        objPtr = new myObject<float>();
        break;
}
```

That brings me lots of problems. First, it is **not flexible** because I have to explicitly declare every type I use inside my framework statically, if I want to also use containers (vector etc) I also would have to explicetly instantiate them.

Second, it is very **slow** to compile. myObject has a lot of templated functions and compiling just 4 of those instantiations would occupy 1.5G of ram and would take a while too. I got to the point that it would occupy 6GB of RAM and take more than 1h (never finished).

So, I opted for **explicit instantiation**. I created several .cpp files (12) that explicetly instantiated myObject with different types, declared myObject templates in a separate file and included just the .h containig template signatures in the code cited before. Although, that sill limits the frameworks capabilities and

**Anybody knows a way to do that purely as a template?** So I need to instantiate only the types being used by the main program? I tried to put the instantiation of myObject inside myRemoteObject, but it didn't work...

ps.: I am using C++2011

Comment: To run code for `myObject<T>` you just **have** to have a compiled version of the code for each specific `T`. Anything else would need magic.

Comment: Templates seem like a terrible approach for this.

Comment: Okay then you know best.

Comment: Usually, if you use a template, when you instantiate the objects with the type you want to use it compiles only parts of the template you use. Although, when you instantiate it explicitly it compiles the whole template for every type you declare... thats what I am trying to avoid. 

The framework is supposed to work with templates, I am not changing it. I also rely on templates to do a safe type cast on the function pointer the programmer passes to the framework.

Comment: Don't downvote just because you don't know how to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to instantiate templates, which are solved at compilation time, with a data type of a message that is solved in run time, too late. My only suggestion is that you use an Abstract Factory design pattern http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern with a getObject method. In the ConcreteFactory, in the implementation of getObject() or createObject(), you instantiate the corresponding object and return it.

Each ConcreteFactory creates an object of certain type (int, float, etc.) and returns it.

For any new type you could create a new plugin with the corresponding ConcreteFactory.

This can help you solve part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is sort of what I am doing. I already have a object creator that creates a object that inherits from a abstract class. I also have implemented dynamic loading that would allow for creating plugins that would allow for expansion in covered types. But I was still hoping that it could be done  in compilation time... it would be transparent to the user.